# What's wrong with these two questions?

Tags: support, question-quality

I posted two question in the past few days that were carefully researched and carefully laid out. The first one got an answer, which I learned from and edited to add what I learned from it.

The first question has votes of -1, the second, -2. Both questions have two votes to close them. I asked in a comment on the first one what was wrong with it, but got no reply. Can you explain to me what is wrong with those questions and why they might be closed?

- [How can I find the target URLs of the tiles on this webpage? (And hidden data too, if possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70858926/how-can-i-find-the-target-urls-of-the-tiles-on-this-webpage-and-hidden-data-to)
- [Can I get more hidden data from this website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70905902/can-i-get-more-hidden-data-from-this-website)

Comment: Your second question does lack focus because you're asking too many questions there. I've voted to close it for that reason. I'm not sure about the first one.

Comment: I find it very hard to understand what's happening in the first question. You talk about some data on some page and some numbers. But there is no concrete example of the shape of the data. You have a link to an external site, so I assume you mean for us to visit it, examine it ourselves, then come up with a solution for you and post it, yet that's not how SO works. All data *for* the question to be answered should be *in* the question. Otherwise when the data in the link changes, the question becomes unanswerable and any existing answers lose their meaning.

Comment: I think you have really miss understood how Q&A websites work. You submit a question and receive an answer. Editing an answer and providing responses far exceeds the editing mechanism of SE communities. To put it simply your questions have some serious quality problems that should be addressed. You basically edited an answer instead of submitting your own answer.

Comment: My questions are about a web scraping problem with a particular website. I don't know what data I could post because the questions are about how to get data that I have not been able to find. If that sort of question is not suitable for SO, can you suggest a better place for it? I don't see a Stack Exchange site for web scraping.

Comment: Your first question is not self contained. It shows no example of what you are working with and it only links to external resources. It shows no example of what you would like to achieve. It shows no attempt at solving the problem (granted that is not necessarily needed, but still) nor any "starting point" for the code that you would like to use to accomplish the task. It's tagged HTML and web-scraping, without specifying a language of interest which clearly will greatly affect any answer. So yeah, there's that...

Comment: If you read the Terms of Service of the site providing the data, you'll find, under "Restrictions on Use", the following: "The Services and the content of the Site may not be copied, displayed, distributed, licensed, modified, published, reposted, reproduced, reused, sold, transmitted, reverse engineered, used to create a derivative work or otherwise used for public or commercial purposes without the express written consent of Verivest in each instance." Now, I don't know if you have "express written consent" (I would think they would have informed you of their API in that case), but take care

Comment: The first question is pretty much "not useful", in the context of a Q&A repository. It is very tailored to you, and you alone. You essentially ask how to scrape a website controlled by javascript; that has surely been asked and answered before. How to scrape that specific site is really not useful for the repository.

Answer (score 5):

It could just be me, but I find the questions a bit hard to follow. It would help if they were a bit more concrete, and if I didn't have to look so closely at an external site to understand them.